# 13.10 Workspace switcher view is duplicated on multiple monitors

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, 13.10, workspaces

I work with an additional monitor connected to my laptop. When I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10, the workspace switcher view has changed. In 13.04 I was getting both of the screens showing one switcher view spread across both screens but now each screen is showing a duplicate view. I liked the old way better. How can I switch it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in CCSM. The following screenshot shows the related page. You can reach it under **Expo settings**. At the bottom of the image, the combo box named **Multi Output Mode** is what I needed. Changing it from `One wall per output` to `One big wall` did it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For 14.04, You can find "Desktop Wall" in CCSM. There is a tab "Viewport Switching" and there is an option called "Multimonitor behavior", you should change it to "Switch seperately"[1]

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIKPE.png

Answer (score -1):

13.10, Desktop-AMD64 Saucy Salamander has the Workspace utility switched off by default.  Install "Unity Tweak Tool", launch the application and click on "Workspace Settings".

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/change-number-of-workspaces-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is not my problem. I already have it enabled, I just want it to work like it did in 13.04.